# Callable interface with executor framework. Why Program didn't exit even after returning from call method

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, executorservice, callable

I am trying to understand callable interface with executor framework . This is working but I am a bit confused why program never exits even after returning from call method.

Code:

`CallableExample.java`

```
package callable1;

import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

public class CallableExample implements Callable<String> {

    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String s = Thread.currentThread().getName();
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
        {
            s += ""+i;
            System.out.println(s);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }

        return s;
    }
}
```

`Tester.java`

```
package callable1;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public class Tester {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        Future<String> ftask = pool.submit(new CallableExample());

        System.out.println("getting result");
        System.out.println("----" + ftask.get());
        System.out.println("main over");
    }
}
```

Comment: It's by design and impl of the thread pool. You need to call `shutdown()` on your executor. You can read more in the javadocs. See also `shutdownNow()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @VladimirVagaytsev . It works, I forgot to shut it down.

Comment: You are welcome :) Feel free to accept the answer if you like it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thread pools of `java.util.concurrent.*` are designed in such a way, so you have to call either `shutdown()` or `shutdownNow()` on your executor. Otherwise the program won't stop. You can find the difference between the methods in the javadocs.